# setinterval doesn't stop in my js code but it should run

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

setinterval doesn't stop in my js code even though my conditional statement becomes false when it reaches 14 and else should be executed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>live site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        @keyframes color {
            0% {
                background: #33CCCC;
            }
            20% {
                background: #33CC36;
            }
            40% {
                background: #B8CC33;
            }
            60% {
                background: #FCCA00;
            }
            80% {
                background: #33CC36;
            }
            100% {
                background: #33CCCC;
            }
        }
        
        body {
            background: #000000;
        }
        
        #list-var {
            background-color: #272727;
            max-width: 400px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        
        p {
            background-color: #161616;
            border-radius: 2px;
            margin: 5px 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: #005e5e;
            padding: 5px 0;
            font-family: fantasy;
        }
        
        .been {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .more {
            background-color: #000000;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: color 9s infinite linear;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="boxing">


        <div id="list-var">
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="more" onclick="more_list();">view more...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<script>
    function more_list() {
        var been_tag = document.getElementsByClassName('been');
        var for_speed = setInterval(sett, 200);
        var i = 0;

        function sett() {
            console.log(i);
            been_tag[i].style.display = "block";

            if (been_tag.length >= i) {
                i++;
            } else {
                clearInterval(for_speed);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

> and error:

index.html:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') at sett (index.html:106:25)

I know that I have a bug, but I tried a lot, but I haven't found that bug

Comment: But I want the code to run when the view more button is clicked

Comment: @Kinglish that's not related. @seacolor get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. It tells you it's trying to access `been_tag[i].style` and `been_tag[i]` is undefined. So your index `i` is going too high. That's because `14 >= 14` is true. So change `>=` to `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is

```
if (been_tag.length >= i) {
    i++;
}
```

Imagine `been_tag` is empty.

```
if (0 >= 0) // true
```

then you will still do the next iteration,

```
 been_tag[0].style.display = "block";
```

even though `been_tag` has nothing in it.  You need to instead do:

```
if (been_tag.length - 1 >= i) {
    been_tag[i].style.display = "block";
    i++
}
```

so that you only do the access of the element at `i` if it actually exists:

```js
function more_list() {
        var been_tag = document.getElementsByClassName('been');
        var for_speed = setInterval(sett, 200);
        var i = 0;

        function sett() {
            if (been_tag.length - 1 >= i) {
                been_tag[i].style.display = "block";
                i++
            } else {
                clearInterval(for_speed);
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
@keyframes color {
            0% {
                background: #33CCCC;
            }
            20% {
                background: #33CC36;
            }
            40% {
                background: #B8CC33;
            }
            60% {
                background: #FCCA00;
            }
            80% {
                background: #33CC36;
            }
            100% {
                background: #33CCCC;
            }
        }
        
        body {
            background: #000000;
        }
        
        #list-var {
            background-color: #272727;
            max-width: 400px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        
        p {
            background-color: #161616;
            border-radius: 2px;
            margin: 5px 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: #005e5e;
            padding: 5px 0;
            font-family: fantasy;
        }
        
        .been {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .more {
            background-color: #000000;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: color 9s infinite linear;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="boxing">


        <div id="list-var">
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p>google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="been">google</p>
            <p class="more" onclick="more_list();">view more...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```